# How to fix text getting cut off at the top in a input?

Tags: html, css

I have an input box as following with the css and html code as following:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="textField" placeholder="type here...">
```

CSS:

```
.textField {
    width: calc(100% - 90px);
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "martian-mono-variable", sans-serif;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
```

For some reason, when I type into the input, or just leave it alone with the placeholder text, the top of the text would be cut off slightly.

(https://imgur.com/fQ29zUA)

I tried changing the padding, margin and the box-sizing attribute (which I tried using stuff off google)

I also tried changing the font size as well as the height of the input, which I found didn't do anything because no matter how small the text is it still gets cut off at the top.

None of that worked, so if somebody can help that'd be great!

Update:
I seem to have resolved it. I set the line-height to 30 (which was coincidentally the height of the box) and it fixed it. Not sure why though...

Comment: The code in your question does not reproduce the image. See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/poQxvpL Without an example it is difficult to help you. Have you tried setting the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sorry I didn't add that in my question but this is supposed to be in there
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/waj8csr.css"> Also I think it is a problem with the monospaced font

Comment: Adding that link in didn't do much. The best thing to do is to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself. I know, that's a bit of work, but you might get a good answer very quickly if you do.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I seem to have found the solution, apparently it fixed it when I set the line-height to 30. Thanks! @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Ah, yes, I thought that it might have been a line-height issue. Anyway, next time when you ask a question try to add code that actually reproduces the problem please.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is an issue with either your font file or your @font-face CSS rule. Martian Mono is a Google font, so if you integrate it as described on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Martian+Mono), if should work perfectly.

```css
.textField {
    width: calc(100% - 90px);
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Martian Mono', monospace;    
    text-indent: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Martian+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<input type="text" class="textField" placeholder="type here...">
```